# How can I change my onedrive for business local sync folder?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I tried to follow these instructions

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-location-where-you-sync-SharePoint-libraries-on-your-computer-ca8a88f6-bc4f-4ec2-a460-864c4e9b2be0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

to change the folder where synced files from my onedrive for business account are stored locally, but there is no option called "stop sync" in my onedrive for business tray icon's right click menu! What can I do?

EDIT

OneDrive for Business v 2016 build 17.3.6

Comment: Logout and log back in is how I changed my onedrive storage location, mines not "OneDrive for Business" tho, it's an office 365 account instead.

Comment: Do me a favor - fire up task manager, see if you have groove.exe running

Comment: I'll try to remember when I'm at my laptop rdp isn't answering now for some reason

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: No groove.exe.  The OneDrive process appears to be called OneDrive.exe on mine.

Comment: OK, if able/motivated please post detailed steps as solution, I will try shortly and mark as accepted if successful.